# Pygame icon() function not changing a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a function that allows for the user to click an icon and set a boolean so that the main loop knows which action to perform. The code is intended to work as click airbrush icon -> set `airbrushMode` to true -> return `airbrushMode` so `paintScreen()` can detect it -> perform the action set by `airbrushMode` in the while loop. I added in print statements to locate the problem. The variable does change, but the variable is not returned, and the airbrush function does not work. It does work when I set `airbrushMode` to true inside `paintScreen()` but setting it to false in the function and outside the function both don't work.

The main function

```
def paintScreen():
    airbrushMode = False
    paint = True
    gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
    message_to_screen('Welcome to PyPaint', black, -300, 'large')
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (50, 120, displayWidth - 100, displayHeight - 240))
    while paint:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button('X', 20, 20, 50, 50, red, lightRed, action = 'quit')
        icon(airbrushIcon, white, 50, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'airbrush')
        icon(pencilIcon, white, 140, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'pencil')
        icon(calligraphyIcon, white, 230, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'calligraphy')
        pygame.display.update()
        if cur[0] >= 50 <= displayWidth - 50 and cur[1] >= 120 <= displayHeight - 120:
            if airbrushMode == True:
                airbrush()
```

the function that creates the icons and detects the action, then returns it

```
def icon(icon, colour, x, y, width, height, inactiveColour, activeColour, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:#if the cursor is over the button
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeColour, (x, y, width, height))
        gameDisplay.blit(icon, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: #if clicked
            print('click')
            if action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif action == 'airbrush':
                airbrushMode = True
                print('airbrush set')
                return airbrushMode
                print('airbrush active')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `icon` does not attempt to change any global variables; it's dealing strictly with its input parameters and local variables.  If you want it to *change* a variable outside its own scope, you need to add

```
global airbrushMode
```

at the top of your function.

Also, if you expect `paintScreen` to recognize the global variable, you must have either a global presence (top-level usage) of that variable, or `paintScreen` also needs the `global` declaration.

For full details, look up global variables in Python.

Comment: So just to clarify, every function that changes a global variable needs to declare it as global, otherwise it is treated as local? Does that also cause python to not declare a "not defined" error?

Comment: Yes to your first question. No to you second question in the sense that the variable has to be defined somewhere anyway. You can't use `global` as a declaration, that's only a way to say "The variable with this name has been declared in the global scope, not here".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for events in `icon()`, perhaps the code would flow more smoothly if it posted an event when the button was pressed.

```
def icon(icon, colour, x, y, width, height, inactiveColour, activeColour, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:#if the cursor is over the button
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeColour, (x, y, width, height))
        gameDisplay.blit(icon, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: #if clicked
            print('click')
            pygame.event.post( pygame.USEREVENT + 1, {} )
```

Then handle these in your main loop:

```
while paint:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1
            airbrushMode = True
```

If it were me, I would make a set of my own event types:

```
import enum

...

class MyEvents( enum.Enum ):
    AIRBRUSH = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    PEN      = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
    PENCIL   = pygame.USEREVENT + 3
```

Which allows:

```
pygame.event.post( MyEvents.AIRBRUSH, {} )

...

elif ( event.type == MyEvents.AIRBRUSH ):
    airbrushMode = True
```